# how to check how many minutes have passed since the user is idle?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I want to write a script that will show how many minutes the user is idle. Since the last touch of the keyboard and mouse. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 command_lines...
 ...
 sleep 60
 echo $var
done
```

Result:

> The computer/user is idle for 1 minute.
>
> The computer/user is idle for 2 minute.
>
> ...
>
> The computer/user is idle for 5 minute.
>
> ...

Can we do that? It can be in Bash, Python, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The "w" command should help, from the man page:

w - Show who is logged on and what they are doing.

```
# w | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $1,$5 }}'
USER IDLE
root 0.00s
```

Comment: Thanks. I mean this isn't the end. Pidgin and screensaver know when the last time I touched a computer. I wonder where you collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard and mouse is not a clear concept on a multiuser system, where there can be multiple X servers running on the machine, some attached to one or more physical keyboards or mice, some not, or remote X servers where terminals running on the machine connect to, or bash shells running over ssh and plenty more ways for "bash" to take input from a user...

The "xprintidle" will give you the idle time of the X server you're connected to (that X server may be local or remote, even local, it may not necessarily be the currently active one on the system)

The modification time of $TTY will tell you the idle time of the terminal.
stat -c %Y "$TTY"
is its last modification time in seconds, which you can substract off "$(date +%s)" (if on a GNU system).